# Cant use single file component. "Registered but never used"

Tags: vue.js

I want to import a single file component ([zoomOnHover](https://github.com/Intera/vue-zoom-on-hover)) into my Product.vue component.
When I try to include it in my  it prints out error: "zoomOnHover is assigned a value but never used".

I'm using vue-cli does this have something to do with webpack or vue-loader?

Basically just doing:

```
<template>
   <zoom-on-hover img-normal="image.jpg"></zoom-on-hover>
</template>

<script>
import zoomOnHover from "../zoomOnHover"

export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: { zoomOnHover },
</script>
```

Comment: do you have a trailing `}` in the `<script>` or is that just copy-paste error?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes a typo sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're doing the following in `../zoomOnHover.js`

```
import ZoomOnHover from "vue-zoom-on-hover"
Vue.use(ZoomOnHover)
```

For the following call:

```
import zoomOnHover from "../zoomOnHover"
```

Which won't work as it's not exporting but instead setting a global component.

Why?: Because of the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-zoom-on-hover

So in `../zoomOnHover.js`, do:

```
import ZoomOnHover from "vue-zoom-on-hover"
export default ZoomOnHover
```

or just use use like:

```
...
<script>
import zoomOnHover from "vue-zoom-on-hover"

export default {
  components: { zoomOnHover },
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! I was using the original zoom-on-hover .. not an npm package.. got it working now